# Помогите с формой слова

Tags: морфология

Полагаясь только на свои силы, я становлюсь более `ЯЗВИМ` или `УЯЗВИМЕЕ`…

Comment: Мне кажется, в этом предложении пропущен предлог "на".

Comment: @IvanOlshansky благодарю, исправил.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Более уязвимее" отпадает по картам Таро, [иначе](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/39-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_fonetika__slovoobrazovanie__morfologiya_i_orfografiya/stages/669-332_stepeni_sravneniya_imen_prilagatelnyh.html#:%7E:text=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5%20%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%8E%D1%82%20%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B5%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F,%E2%80%93%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B9%20(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C).):

> При образовании сравнительной и превосходной степени нельзя
> одновременно использовать простую и сложную форму степеней сравнения.
> Неправильно: более красивее, более тяжелее, наиболее спокойнейший.

"Более уязвим" - нормально, но вот я вот так не скажу, скажу: *более уязвимым* или *уязвимее*.

---

Оу! У Вас, оказывается есть форма "язвим"?! О_о Ни-ни, низзя. По картам Таро.